# Copying table from Excel to Word bookmark using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

Pls help! I'm new at this! I want to transfer table from sheet "Table1" from excel to a Bookmark1 in an existing Word (Template fisa de esantionare var.4.docx).

The problem with this macro is that the table is transferred to word, but it erases all the information from word. And the table does not appear in the designated Bookmark1 place. Thanks.

I tried to modify the Macro line, and that does not work.

```
' CREATE A RANGE FOR THE TABLE INSIDE WORD DOCUMENT.
   Dim oRange
   Set oRange = oDoc.Range

    with:
    Dim oRange
    Set oRange = oDoc.Bookmark("Bookmark1")

    Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    On Error Resume Next

' FIRST GET THE ROWS COLUMNS OF A USED RANGE.

Dim iTotalRows As Integer   ' GET TOTAL USED RANGE ROWS.
iTotalRows = Worksheets("Table1").UsedRange.Rows.Count


Dim iTotalCols As Integer   ' GET TOTAL COLUMNS.
iTotalCols = Worksheets("Table1").UsedRange.Columns.Count


' WORD OBJECT.
Dim oWord As Object
Set oWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
oWord.Visible = True
oWord.Activate

' ADD A DOCUMENT TO THE WORD OBJECT.
Dim oDoc
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\stefan.georgescu\Desktop\Template fisa de esantionare var.4.docx")



 ' CREATE A RANGE FOR THE TABLE INSIDE WORD DOCUMENT.
Dim oRange
Set oRange = oDoc.Range

' CREATE AND  DEFINE TABLE STRUCTURE USING
    ' THE ROWS AND COLUMNS EXTRACTED FROM EXCEL USED RANGE.
oDoc.Tables.Add oRange, iTotalRows, iTotalCols


' CREATE A TABLE OBJECT.
Dim oTable
Set oTable = oDoc.Tables(1)
oTable.Borders.Enable = True      ' YES, WE WANT BORDERS.


Dim iRows, iCols As Integer


' LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW AND COLUMN TO EXTRACT DATA IN EXCEL.
For iRows = 1 To iTotalRows
    For iCols = 1 To iTotalCols
        Dim txt As Variant
        txt = Worksheets("Table1").Cells(iRows, iCols)
        oTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Text = txt        ' COPY (OR WRITE) DATA TO THE TABLE.


        ' BOLD HEADERS.
        If Val(iRows) = 1 Then
            objTable.cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Font.Bold = True
        End If
    Next iCols
Next iRows

Set oWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

After you add the document to the word object.

You have:

```
' CREATE A RANGE FOR THE TABLE INSIDE WORD DOCUMENT.
Dim oRange
Set oRange = oDoc.Range
```

You need:

```
' CREATE A RANGE FOR THE TABLE INSIDE WORD DOCUMENT.
Dim oRange
Set oRange = oDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of issues with the code shown in the question - they may not have been obvious due to `On Error Resume Next`. That should be commented out, especially when in the testing stage. This command simply ignores errors, so it won't tell you when something is not working and, even more important, there will be no information as to *why* the result isn't what's expected. I've commented that line out in the sample code, below.

I tried to leave as much the same as possible, but I did move some of the declarations and instantiations in a more logical order.

Although it's not at the beginning of the code, since the question is about setting a target range to a bookmark position, that's done as follows. Note that the bookmark name should be in quotes. Depending on the type of bookmark (whether it marks a point or contains content) the bookmark may be removed. (A boookmark with content will be removed, as will the content; a "point bookmark" will remain, but will not contain the table.) This can be changed with extended code if the bookmark should be retained or should contain the table.

```
Set oRange = oDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range
```

Note that it's usually better to instantiate ("Set") an object when it's being created, rather than after-the-fact. So, for example

```
Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open
Set oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add
```

Since only the first row will be bolded there's no need to check in the loop whether it's the first row and then bold - every "If" costs time/resources. So I moved that command out of the loop, removed the `If` and added the correct variable name (`oTable`, not `objTable` which hasn't been declared anywhere).

When finishing a procedure that uses objects in another application (Word object in Excel, as here) it's important to release *all* objects, not just the application. And this should be done in the reverse order they were created. I've added those additional `Set` to `Nothing` lines at the end.

Note that, not having the Excel data, I couldn't test this procedure, so there could be small syntax errors.

```
Sub TableFromXlToWd()
'    On Error Resume Next

    ' FIRST GET THE ROWS COLUMNS OF A USED RANGE.

    Dim iTotalRows As Integer   ' GET TOTAL USED RANGE ROWS.
    iTotalRows = Worksheets("Table1").UsedRange.Rows.Count

    Dim iTotalCols As Integer   ' GET TOTAL COLUMNS.
    iTotalCols = Worksheets("Table1").UsedRange.Columns.Count

    ' WORD OBJECT.
    Dim oWord As Object
    Set oWord = CreateObject(Class:="Word.Application")
    oWord.Visible = True
    oWord.Activate

    ' ADD A DOCUMENT TO THE WORD OBJECT.
    Dim oDoc As Object  'Word.Document
    Set oDoc = oWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\stefan.georgescu\Desktop\Template fisa de esantionare var.4.docx")       

     ' CREATE A RANGE FOR THE TABLE INSIDE WORD DOCUMENT.
    Dim oRange As Object 'Word.Range
    Set oRange = oDoc.Bookmarks("Bookmark1").Range

    ' CREATE AND  DEFINE TABLE STRUCTURE USING
        ' THE ROWS AND COLUMNS EXTRACTED FROM EXCEL USED RANGE.
    Dim oTable As Object 'Word.Table
    Set oTable = oDoc.Tables.Add(oRange, iTotalRows, iTotalCols)
    oTable.Borders.Enable = True      ' YES, WE WANT BORDERS.

    Dim iRows, iCols As Integer
    oTable.Cell(iRows, iCols).Range.Font.Bold = True        

    ' LOOP THROUGH EACH ROW AND COLUMN TO EXTRACT DATA IN EXCEL.
    For iRows = 1 To iTotalRows
        For iCols = 1 To iTotalCols
            Dim txt As Variant
            txt = Worksheets("Table1").Cells(iRows, iCols)
            oTable.Cell(iRows, iCols).Range.text = txt        ' COPY (OR WRITE) DATA TO THE TABLE.
        Next iCols
    Next iRows
    Set oTable = Nothing
    Set oDoc = Nothing
    Set oWord = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: New task: I want te move multiple tables from this Table1 sheet, maybe set a specific text above next table (e.g. Chapter III.1) and to copy the below table to Boomark 2, and so on...next table (Chapter III.2), to diferent Bookmark3 in the Word doc. What we've done so far is just for one table from XL to one Bookmark in designated WD. Need your help!

Comment: All tables will be in one sheet, and move them to word "Template fisa de esantionare var.4.dotm" in diferent Bookmars 2/3/4/.....48.

Comment: @Fane Ask a new question - and be clear on what you want to do: 'maybe' doesn't cut it.

Comment: @macroprod: I would like to add a new question, but I am not allowed, only afer 4 days...If you can help me please with this new task. Thank you!